# Java Maven project won't get deployed to Heroku

Tags: java, maven, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a simple app using Heroku but I keep on getting the same error which is:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project
```

I thought there is a problem with my pom.xml file buta after changing it multiple times, it still didn't work and I can't seem to figure out why.

Here is my pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>UserManagement</groupId>
  <artifactId>UserManagement</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>Repo-X</name>
  <description>Software repository</description>
  <dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>junit</groupId>
<artifactId>junit</artifactId>
<version>4.8.2</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <release>12</release>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
      </plugin>
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals><goal>copy</goal></goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                         <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
                        <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
                                <version>8.0.30.2</version>
                     <destFileName>webapp-runner.jar</destFileName>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: It seems that there should be more to the error - is that really all it says?

Answer (score 0):

To solve the error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project
```

I'd suggest several options:

1. try to add [explicitly](https://pretagteam.com/question/unable-to-build-using-maven-with-error-failed-to-execute-goal-orgapachemavenpluginsmavencompilerplugin31compile) `properties` inside your `POM` before dependencies like:

> ```
> <properties>
>      <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
>      <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
>      <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>   
> </properties>
> ```

*based on *your* Java project version.

2. try to [configure](https://www.cnblogs.com/wang-xiaohui/p/14889704.html) by specifying a `<configuration>` element in format:

> ```
> <plugin>
>    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> 
>    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
>    <version>3.8.1</version>     
>    <configuration>
>        <source>1.8</source>
>        <target>1.8</target>
>    </configuration>
> </plugin>
> ```

3. try to upgrade/downgrade version of `maven-compiler-plugin`

then redeploy again.

If nothing helps, improve your question with updated investigations, please.

---

Also it'd be more informative if you update the question with your specific attempts, what exactly you tried to do to solve it.